# Cabal-installing link fails with undefined references in Fedora 20

Tags: haskell, cabal

Trying to install Yi fails because it fails to install vty.
When trying to install vty through cabal install vty, or cabal install after cloning the vty repo, I get error messages from undefined references, related to terminfo, such as this one.

> /usr/local/lib/terminfo-0.4.0.1/ghc-7.6.3/libHSterminfo-0.4.0.1.a(Base.o): In function s4NX_info:
>   /tmp/ghc26691_0/ghc26691_1.o:(.text+0x20b1): undefined reference to cur_term

What does the error mean exactly?

The file `/usr/local/lib/terminfo-0.4.0.1/ghc-7.6.3/libHSterminfo-0.4.0.1.a` does exist. I tried in a sandbox, reinstalling cabal deleting its folders, yum-installing ncurses-devel, cabal-installing terminfo, yum-installing ghc-terminfo-devel, cabal-installing terminfo from a cloned repo, and combinations of those things (without really understanding what I was doing) to no avail.

I am in Fedora 20. Using Cabal 1.22.0.0 (installed an older Cabal with yum, then did cabal install cabal-install, and removed the yum's cabal). `Cabal list terminfo` right now shows 3 installed versions of terminfo (0.3.2.5, 0.4.0.0 and 0.4.0.1). `ghc-pkg list` shows v0.4.0.1 and 0.3.2.5 as installed (and not hidden) in the global database (I think. The one in /usr/lib64/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d)

I would appreciate some help to get Yi installed and to understand how to proceed with these issues. Thanks

Comment: " then did cabal install cabal-install, and removed the yum's cabal)."


You have ~/.cabal/bin at the front of your path as well right?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce using Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug), The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3, cabal-install version 1.22.0.1 using version 1.22.1.1 of the Cabal library installing yi 0.11.2.

Does your problem still exist using these newer versions?

Comment: Hey, thanks Codygman. I ended up fixing this with the help of the #haskell IRC channel and some fighting. I didn't end up understanding it very clearly, however, and I don't remember the details any more. Some package said in its metadata that it required some C headers instead of ncurses (I think), and it worked when I installed an older version of it. If I understood or remembered it better I would post it as an answer.

Comment: However, my Cabal version is 1.22.0.0. It's nice to know that its possible to install yi without downgrading anything.